# Unable to Create or Open JavaScript file in Android-Studio

Tags: javascript, cordova, android-studio

I'm Using Cordova, Phone-Gap, with Android Studio, I have Created a Project it's working fine but I'm unable to create or open existing java script file in android studio, even existing JavaScript files are showing like a folder or directory when I click on them nothing happens,
Looking for a quick response Thanks. https://i.stack.imgur.com/93fBH.png

Comment: There are many who can find mistakes in my question but no one is here to answer it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Reset my Android Studio now All is Well.
Thanks You anyway :P.